# Append to whitelist in a subclassed MVC3 Model, using BindAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, binding, attributes

I use a whitelist to bind querystring/form values to my model. This is done by:

```
[Bind(Include = "Size,Color,Age,SizeOfTeeth")]
public class AnimalModel { ... }
```

But say I have a subclassed Model, called ElephantModel, and I'd like to keep the whitelist from the base class, and add some of the derived class' properties to it. How would I do that?

I tried:

```
[Bind(Include += "TrunkLength,Personality")]
public class ElephantModel : AnimalModel { ... }
```

But of course that doesn't work. I suspect this is actually more of an "Attributes" question, than a "binding" question, but I can't figure out what syntax to use.

TIA!Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing BindAttribute seems best, but its marked sealed. So then I thought to modify the attribute in the subclass' constructor, but that uses reflection which I'd prefer to avoid unless necessary.

So I chose this approach for the base class:

```
[Bind(Include = WhiteList)]
public class AnimalModel {

  protected const string WhiteList = "Size,Color,Age,SizeOfTeeth";

}
```

Then for the subclass:

```
[Bind(Include = WhiteList)]
public class ElephantModel : AnimalModel {

  new protected const string WhiteList = AnimalModel.WhiteList + ",TrunkLength,Personality";

}
```

Unfortunately this means the attribute must be REdefined for the subclass (as you are modifying it). But that's no biggie.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not possible due to the nature of attributes in C#. Attributes represent metadata that is baked into the resulting assembly at compile time meaning that they can only take expressions known at compile time.

One possible workaround that I would recommend you is to use view models. So for example you would have the following view model in which you would include only the properties that really should be bound:

```
public class UpdateElephantViewModel
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int SizeOfTeeth { get; set; }
    public int TrunkLength { get; set; }
    public string Personality { get; set; }
}
```

which also might look like this if the base view model would be reused:

```
public class UpdateAnimalViewModel
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int SizeOfTeeth { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateElephantViewModel : UpdateAnimalViewModel
{
    public int TrunkLength { get; set; }
    public string Personality { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could have the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(UpdateElephantViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

and finally map between the view model and the actual Elephant model. To ease the mapping between those two types you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: +1 : I can't understate the awesomeness of ViewModels (which are, of course, tightly bound to the view) as opposed to using common domain models (aka poco's) as the view's model. Well said (again) Darin :)

Comment: Darin: Appreciate your input. I am using an input model with all those properties, and I perform rigorous validation, check for under-posting, over-posting, XSS vectors, etc. That is why I need the BindAttribute. As for AutoMapper, I dislike the magic in such tools, and prefer to stick to old-school OO whenever possible.

Comment: Pure: Prefer to accept input models into my controller, which should be concerned with domain logic. Then the controller creates the appropriate view model and passes it to the view. Again, old-school encapsulation, less magic, easier to maintain.